# When I try to link a button from the main.storyboard to view controller.m file, It does not show up.(Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a music player with play, pause and stop buttons using single view application and I have added  different view controllers which play a song once clicked.The first view controller I was able to connect, but I can't link the other two view controllers to the view controller.m file.

Comment: please show some code , then we can help you

Comment: You need make new class for other two view controllers

Comment: Are you holding down the right mouse button?

Comment: I had to select the class name in the view controller in order to create a action.That fixed my problem,I am now moving to the coding part.Thanks all for your response.